# Is KeyedCollection meant only when Key determines the equality of the items in it?

Tags: c#, semantics, equality, keyedcollection

I think this is a common problem we run into.

```
class Person
{
    public string place;
    public string name;

    public Person(string place, string name)
    {
        this.place = place;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;

        return name == other.name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Person);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return place + " - " + name;
    }
}
```

Say I have this class. I can implement a `KeyedCollection` like this:

```
class Collection : KeyedCollection<string, Person>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(Person item)
    {
        return item.place;
    }
}
```

The case here is that the default `Equals` is based on `name` of the `Person` but in my case I'm creating a custom `collection` that will have only one `Person` per `place`. In other words `place` will be unique in `collection`.

```
Person p1 = new Person("Paris", "Paul");
Person p2 = new Person("Dubai", "Ali");

var collection = new Collection { p1, p2 };
var p3 = new Person("Paris", "Jean");
if (!collection.Contains(p3))
    collection.Add(p3);   // explosion
```

I understand the problem. The `Contains(Person)` overload is that of `Collection<T>.Contains(T)` which does a value based linear search while `Add(Person)` does adds the value to the internal dictionary which can cause the duplicate key exception. Here, had equality was based on `place`, this problem wouldn't have existed.

I can come with a workaround:

```
class Collection : KeyedCollection<string, Person>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(Person item)
    {
        return item.place;
    }

    new public bool Contains(Person item)
    {
        return this.Contains(GetKeyForItem(item));
    }
}
```

But this again means if I do a general

```
var p3 = new Person("Paris", "Jean");
bool b = collection.Contains(p3); //true
```

returns `true`, but in reality `Jean` doesn't exist in `collection` yet. So my question is, does `KeyedCollection<K, T>` makes sense only when `Equals` is based on just the `K` part of the `T`? My question is little on the semantics side. **I'm not asking for solution, but just knowing is there a general understanding on when would a `KeyedCollection` make sense?** I couldn't find anything relevant on this subject from documentation.

### Update:

I have found the exact problem mentioned here http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/633980-framework-bug-keyedcollection-t

where the asker has submitted a bug report to MS. To quote him (dated Apr 18 '07):

> I submitted this as a bug to Microsoft, and they have verified it and
> accepted it. It's Issue ID 271542, and can be tracked [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=271542):
>
> "We have reproduced this bug on WinXP pro SP2 and VSTS2005 SP1, and
> we are sending this bug to the appropriate group within the Visual
> Studio Product Team for triage and resolution."

While I don't think this is a bug, this is an annoyance surely. But just wondering how did MS accept this as a bug in the first place (*expectedly, the page can't be found now*). Imo, its just poorly thought out inheritance model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seem to be two things that make sense to ask the collection:

- whether it contains ***the*** person named Jean who lives in Paris, and
- whether it contains ***a*** person who lives in Paris.

The [KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) provides exactly two methods to ask these questions:

- the [Contains(TItem) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132407.aspx), and
- the [Contains(TKey) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132452.aspx).

***The** person named Jean who lives in Paris* is not the same person as ***the*** person named Paul who lives in Paris ([Person.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx)). But if there is ***a*** person who lives in Paris, then according to your rules there cannot be ***another*** person who lives in Paris.

So basically you have to ask the collection the right question before adding a new person:

```
if (!collection.Contains(p3.place))
    collection.Add(p3);
```

---

For convenience, you could add a TryAdd Method to the class that returns if **the** person was successfully added or if there is already **a** person in the collection who lives in the same place:

```
public bool TryAdd(Person person)
{
    if (Contains(GetKeyForItem(person)))
        return false;
    Add(person);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Basically you're saying there is no hard rule that the key (`place`) must be the choice for determining equality for items in a `KeyedCollection` and that I have to use the right method..

Comment: And the strange thing, MS has accepted it as a bug! Pls see my update.